# How To Embed JAR Library into Project with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am working on a bukkit plugin (for Minecraft) and I would like to include the JavaMail JAR, I am using eclipse to develop the plugin and I cannot figure out how to make it reference the included mail.jar when the mail function executes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paste the JAR file within a folder in your Java Project, then Right-Click-> Properties -> Build Path-> Libraries-> Add External Jar and select the JAR you just included.